# Visual studio (whole thing) 2010 fails to upgrade older solutions?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-6

Visual C++ 2010 constantly fails with upgrading Visual C++ 6.0 Workspaces to the new format. It keeps having problems with the same project file, which opens perfectly in Visual C++ 6.0 (Which I'd really like to refrain from using.) I also tried importing only the project file with no avail, and then even just moving the headers and code into a new project, which obviously doesn't work. (the project was the SoundFX 2000 source code, by Software System Consultants)

I also attempted to open an older version of a C# Workspace, and that failed to. Its always the same error: "error", no more, no less...

I'm running this on an old, XP machine (for backwards compatibility testing).
On my 7 machine with Visual C# 2015, it had no issue converting Visual C# 2008 code. Does anyone know what is going on? why can't I convert it? how can I get a more detailed output than just "error"

Comment: What's the reason for using VS 2010 instead of VS 2015?

Comment: VS 2015 does not support Windows XP. I use XP as my main program PC because of compatibility testing, and don't want constantly send files back and forth. (No, a virtual machine is not an option)

Comment: VS 2015 does support XP if you change the **Platform Toolset** in your project configuration.  Also why don't you use a VM with XP installed instead of two separate machines?  The days of having two or more completely separate machines to develop on are waning.

Comment: What I am suggesting is that VS 2015 may be all you need.  Just set the platform toolset to the lowest targeted operating system.   You may need the Platform SDK installed for that OS, but I currently use VS 2015 and set my Platform Toolset to "Visual Studio 2013 - XP", which was the last compiler toolset to support XP.  The programs produced with this setup run on XP without any issues.

Comment: I tried using a virtual machine, it is way too slow on my under-powered computer and doesn't support 3D Acceleration. Visual Studio 2015 doesn't install on XP, and even though it will make programs for it. I will try the Platform Tool-set thing though! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get detailed info of the error, add the following section in the **configuration** section and after **configSections**  section in the devenv.exe.config file located in Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE subfolder of the VS installation folder:

```
<system.diagnostics>
      <switches>
        <add name="CPS" value="4" />
    </switches>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" 
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
          initializeData="c:\VS2010Debug.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This will create the file c:\VS2010Debug.log (you can change the name and location obviously) after VS is restarted.

Next you must create a cmd file (e.g. VS2010.cmd) with the following contents:

```
cd /d "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\ide\" 
start devenv.exe /Log
exit
```

Again you must edit the above path according to your own VS2010 installation location.

This will log VS activities in a log file located here (by default):

**%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Version\ActivityLog.xml**

Start VS 2010 by executing the cmd file, convert your project and examine the log file for additional info about the conversion errors.